# Convert a definite integral to a contour integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

There is an integral equation that shows up in scattering problems in electromagnetics where the kernel looks like this:

$$G(z, z') = \frac{1}{8\pi^2} \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi' g\left(z, z', \phi'\right)$$

where

$$g\left(z, z', \phi'\right) = \frac{\exp\left(-jk\sqrt{\left(z-z'\right)^2+4a^2\sin^2\left(\phi'/2\right)}\right)}{\sqrt{\left(z-z'\right)^2+4a^2\sin^2\left(\phi'/2\right)}}$$

and where $k$ is the free space wavenumber and $a>0$ is the radius of a wire in question.

Could someone help me write this integral as a contour integral?

Comment: Have you tried changing the variable of integration to $u=e^{i\phi’}$?

Comment: I got $${\frac {{{\rm e}^{-ik\sqrt { \left( z-{\it z'} \right) ^{2}-4\,i{a}^{2
}\sinh \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( u \right)  \right) }}}}{\sqrt { \left( 
z-{\it z'} \right) ^{2}-4\,i{a}^{2}\sinh \left( 1/2\,\ln  \left( u
 \right)  \right) }}}
.$$ What do I do next?

Comment: What about $d\phi’$? Do you understand what the contour is?